# Return null from dayofyear function - Spark SQL

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Databricks & Spark/Scala.
I'm currently working on a machine learning to do sales forecasting.
I used the function dayofyear to create features.
The only problem is that returns me null value.
I tried with this csv because i was using an another one and i thought this could come from this.
But apparently, i was wrong.
I read the docs about this function but the description is really short.
I tried with dayofmonth or weekofyear, same result.

Can you explain me how I can fix this ? What am I doing wrong ?

```
val path = "dbfs:/databricks-datasets/asa/planes/plane-data.csv"
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(path)

display(df)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df2 = df.withColumn("dateofyear", dayofyear(df("issue_date")))
display(df2)
```

Here's the result : [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WePTL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the `issue_date` to `timestamp` before using `dayofyear` function as

```
data.withColumn("issue_date", unix_timestamp($"issue_date", "MM/dd/yyyy").cast(TimestampType))
      .withColumn("dayofyear", dayofyear($"issue_date"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ! 
I didn't think to that. I saw on the docs that we can use this on string. 
It works perfectly.

Comment: Glad that helped you :)